# How to fetch all contacts record in ios xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, fetch, contacts

I want to fetch all contact records in iOS Xamarin. 
I used code --> https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/shared_resources/contacts/find_a_contact/

**Code:**

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        Util.CurrentView = this;
        _View = this;

        var predicate = CNContact.GetPredicateForContacts("Appleseed");
        var fetchKeys = new NSString[] { CNContactKey.GivenName, CNContactKey.FamilyName };
        var store = new CNContactStore();
        NSError error;
        var contacts = store.GetUnifiedContacts(predicate, fetchKeys, out error);
    }
```

**Error code:**

> This Error: **Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception
>   thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: +[CNContact
>   predicateForContactsMatchingName:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   class 0x1a3e1ec**

I already add `[Export("predicateForContactsMatchingName:")]`, but it didn't help.

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

"Appleseed" is the search term used in the example. Seems like your mismatch is because none of the contacts match with the predicate.

Anyways, during my own implementation I ran into many issues. Below is a full solution to fetch all contacts in iOS Xamarin.

**First: Add permission in info.plist**

```
<key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires contacts access to function properly.</string>
```

**Second: Create a Model for Contacts info**

In the example below I only add 3 fields

```
using System.Collections;

/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
namespace YourNameSpace
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public class UserContact
    {
        public UserContact()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="givenName"></param>
        /// <param name="familyName"></param>
        /// <param name="emailId"></param>
        public UserContact(string givenName, string familyName, IList emailId)
        {
            GivenName = givenName;
            FamilyName = familyName;
            EmailId = emailId;
        }

        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
        public string GivenName { get; set; }
        public string FamilyName { get; set; }
        public IList EmailId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Third: Read Contacts**

```
public IEnumerable<UserContact> GetAllContactsAndEmails()
        {
            var keysTOFetch = new[] { CNContactKey.GivenName, CNContactKey.FamilyName, CNContactKey.EmailAddresses };
            NSError error;
            CNContact[] contactList;
            var ContainerId = new CNContactStore().DefaultContainerIdentifier;
            using (var predicate = CNContact.GetPredicateForContactsInContainer(ContainerId))

            using (var store = new CNContactStore())
            {
                contactList = store.GetUnifiedContacts(predicate, keysTOFetch, out error);
            }
            var contacts = new List<UserContact>();

            foreach (var item in contactList)
            {
                if (null != item && null != item.EmailAddresses)
                {
                    contacts.Add(new UserContact
                    {
                        GivenName = item.GivenName,
                        FamilyName = item.FamilyName,
                        EmailId = item.EmailAddresses.Select(m => m.Value.ToString()).ToList()
                    });
                }
            }
            return contacts;
        }
```

**Make sure you include contact attributes you need in KeysToFetch array**